# Collection was modified exception when DataTable is saved to a file

Tags: c#, datatable

I got this weird exception:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.

This is my code:

```
void WriteTask(DataTable dt, string outputFilePath, bool final)
{
        if (final)
        {
            exiting = false;
            dbWriteTime = 0;
        }

        while (!exiting)
        {
            if (TimeCurrent - dbWriteTime >= 10)
            {
                try
                {
                    dbWriteTime = TimeCurrent;
                    dt.WriteXml(outputFilePath + "users.xml");                        

                    if (final)
                        exiting = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
}
```

This is a task that every 10 seconds writes datatable to a file. I have searched this exception online, what I can find is that this exception occurs in a `foreach` loop if the collection has been changed. But I'm not using `foreach`.

Comment: Where do you get this exception? I doubt this is the relevant code as there is no enumeration here.

Comment: stacktrace returned a line in this task

Comment: Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.
   at System.Data.RBTree`1.RBTreeEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.XmlDataTreeWriter.Save(XmlWriter xw, Boolean writeSchema)
   at System.Data.DataTable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer, XmlWriteMode mode, Boolean writeHierarchy)
   at System.Data.DataTable.WriteXml(String fileName, XmlWriteMode mode, Boolean writeHierarchy)
   at IllSkillzBot_app.IllSkillzBot.WriteTask(DataTable dt, String outputFilePath, Boolean final) in dir line 1243

Comment: The call to `dt.WriteXml(outputFilePath + "users.xml");` is using a foreach internally. I'm guessing you manipulate the data while this task runs every 10s on a different thread, this is causing the issue. You could try looking into [`lock`ing an object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) to avoid the `dt` being used by 2 threads at once.

Comment: I cant lock the thread that is working with dataset. It's a real time application and some data might be lost while it's locked.

Comment: I can create a buffer dataset, so thread that is saving will be working with it. But Im guessing that process of copying dataset will be using foreach as well